# Javascript/Jquery - Setting default value in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using javascript/jquery is there a way to set a variable to a default value if no value is passed in the function? For example

```
function someFunction(data1,data2)
{


}
```

If data1 or data 2 is empty it gives me an undefined value. In php I could do just this:

```
function somefunction(data1 = '',data2 = '')
{


}
```

So if no variable is passed or data1 or data 2 it defaults to ''. In JS/Jquery do I have to check if there is a value and set it accordingly?

```
function someFunction(data1,data2)
{

if(!data1) {

data1 = '';

}

if(!data2) {

data2 = ''

}

}
```

Just seems alot needs to be done to check if variable is empty or not to give it a default value.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
function foo(bar) {
    bar = bar || 'default';
}
```

(Alternatively, if you only ever use `bar` once, you can just replace that usage with `bar || <default value>` and skip the intermediate assignment.)

Comment: This works as long as `bar` is not allowed to have a value which evaluates to `false`. In this case, the longer ternary operator has to be used (to compare against the "invalid" value explicitly).

Answer (score 4):

```
function someFunction(data){
    data = data || 'my value';
}
```

The only problem with this is that the `0`, `false` and `undefined` are treated the same:

```
someFunction(1); // data = 1;
someFunction(-1); // data = -1;
someFunction(); // data = 'my value';
someFunction(0); // data = 'my value';
someFunction(false); // data = 'my value';
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
function foo(optionalArg) {
    optionalArg = optionalArg|| 'defaultValue';
}
```

as long as you never pass a value to the parameter.
This logic fails if optionalArg is passed
Try this instead:

```
function foo(optionalArg) {
    optionalArg = (typeof optionalArg === "undefined") ? "defaultValue" : optionalArg;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use jquery's extend method but define defaults in the code like below

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function (settings) {
    var options = jQuery.extend({
        name: "MyPlugin",
        target: document,
        onOpen: function () {},
        onClose: function () {},
        onSelect: function () {}
    }, settings);
}
```

now you could do

```
$("#divId").myPlugin({
    target: $("#div2")
};
```

this will now override the `document` target defined inside the defaults with element `having div2 as id`.

Comment: I think this would only work for functions in jQuery plugins, right?

Comment: @bean5 Yes correct. If you want to build something that has to do with configuration and defaults i bet that piece of code is well worth written as plugin than global function.